# What does it mean when R Shiny app downloadHandler only opens a new tab with new instance of app, no download?

Tags: r, shiny

I have a Shiny app that includes multiple uses of downloadHandler() to trigger downloads of .csv, .rmd, and .zip files. It's supposed to just trigger download, but instead all of the downloadHandlers except for one just open a new browser tab with a new instance of the app running, except for one. That random one (formatted identically to the others) correctly triggers a download and no new tab opens.

Apart from the specific code that I'm using, what does it mean when downloadHandler() causes a new browser tab to open running a new instance of the app, with no download?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example, as it stands we have nothing to work with here.

Comment: Sure, so I provide basic code and a more detailed walkthrough including a link to a Github reprex when these were all working correctly here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70542574/all-but-one-downloadhandler-with-shiny-fluent-not-working-just-opens-new-tab-ru. Unfortunately, noone has been able to answer the question based on the specific code, so instead I'm asking a much more basic question about downloadHandler. Simply, what does it mean when a usage of downloadHandler opens a new tab with a new instance of the app but no download. Thanks!

Comment: Side note, if you'd like to slog through 20,000 lines of code, I'm happy to share the full repo with you too haha. I appreciate any advice here r2evans, thanks.

Comment: I see. It's out of my scope for size, complexity, and packages. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the same issue and found this solution which worked for me:

```
library(shiny)

ui = fluidPage(actionButton("Download", "Download"))

server =  function(input, output) {
  observe({
    if (input$Download == TRUE){
      filename= paste0(Sys.Date(), "_iris.csv")
      write.csv(iris, filename)
    }
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, 
         server = server)
```

Comment: Oh interesting, so you don't use downloadHandler at all. Great, I'll try that and get back to you asap with whether it worked or not. Generally speaking, have you found any drawbacks to using that approach in lieu of downloadHandler? Finally, were you able to find out WHY it was causing that exact behavior for you? I'm really curious to know at this point what exactly is happening between Shiny and the browser to trigger that behavior.

Comment: No, I found solutions for what is the reason if just a white tab opens and nothing happens ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21937700/12242625)). But for my specific point I hadn't dug deeper because i simply needed an export and this solution was sufficient. So it's a workarround and there might be a better and more elegant solution. But if you don't find one or it gets to complicated, give it a try.

Comment: So this workaround works, thanks for the suggestion! We've tracked our root issue down further and it turns out that it seems to be an interaction with leaflet::setView() and our hidden downloadButtons which makes ZERO sense. As soon as setView() is called in our leaflet objects, the downloadHandlers start breaking. As soon as all setView() instances are removed, the downloadHandlers all work again. So weird.

Comment: Thank you for feedback! Interessting to know.